# php htaccess url redirect based on argument

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a domain where the urls can be like

```
www.mydomain.com/home.php?q=abc
```

Is it possible to Let users enter url as `www.mydomain.com/abc`, and I  somehow get the "abc" part, do all database queries, and show the contents of home.php?q=abc, but keep the url as `www.mydomain.com/abc`

I do know how to get `/home.php?q=abc` to show as /home?q=abc using htaccess.

Comment: Btw what you describe is EXACTLY how modern applications work :)

Comment: @Panique I understand. It is just my humble attempt on that line.

Answer (score 0):

PLease try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ home.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```